# CSS/JS Image Text Overlay Like Lattice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering whether [image: this] is possible or not. I'm learning JS and CSS and searched on google and StackOverflow but go no answer. The one of the S from ALYSSA is being covered by the hand of the model. If you don't want to explain just tell me the name of the effect.

Comment: I would guess this is just an image created in Photoshop.

Comment: You can overlay elements on top of each other using the `z-index` property and `absolute` positioning. But as pointed out it's likely just done in Photoshop

Comment: @Brad I know but can this be achieved using CSS and JS and still make is responsive?

Comment: Please update your question with the desire to make it responsive. That makes a big difference to the answers you get.

Answer (score 1):

Although this image is built in Photoshop, you could reproduce this by using the `mask` CSS attribute to put the arm over the text. You would end up with 3 layers: the main image in the background, the text layer and then the main image again but with a mask. The mask image would be created in a graphics program and would be mostly black except for the piece of arm that would be white.

Answer (score -4):

I think it is done by PhotoShop or any other image editing app.
https://assets.awwwards.com/awards/external/2017/02/58ad59d717a01.jpg
it is just an image. no coding.

you can use z-index though.
put ALYS in different element, SA MI in different element and LLER in different element.

Than in css arrange z-index of these elements accordingly.

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

IMP: An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Comment: his question is about a hover effect and not about a picture